# Terraform is deleting resources randomly when using for_each

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create security groups rules from a map of objects in Terraform, however sometimes terraform delete those roles and this is happening randomly. We are using s3 as backend and dynamodb locks.

This is my security group resource

```
resource "aws_security_group" "ec2_jumper_sg" {
  name        = "${var.app_name}-private-sg"
  description = "Security Group for Private EC2 instance"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

  egress {
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [var.vpc_cidr]
  }
}
```

Those are the rules created with the `for_each` attached to the above security group:

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ec2_jumper_sg_databases_egress" {
  for_each = var.databases

  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.ec2_jumper_sg.id
  from_port                = each.value.port
  to_port                  = each.value.port
  source_security_group_id = each.value.securityGroupId
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  type                     = "egress"
}
```

And this is my variable map:

```
variable "databases" {
  type = map(object({
    id: string
    securityGroupId: string
    port: number
  }))

  default = {
    "db-1": {
      id : "db-1",
      securityGroupId : "sg-000000000",
      port : 5432
    },
    "db-2": {
      id : "db2",
      securityGroupId : "sg-000000000",
      port : 3306
    }
  }
}
```

When the rules do not exist it will create them, however when they are there it will delete them:

```
      - {
              - cidr_blocks      = []
              - description      = ""
              - from_port        = 3306
              - ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
              - prefix_list_ids  = []
              - protocol         = "tcp"
              - security_groups  = [
                  - "sg-0000000",
                ]
              - self             = false
              - to_port          = 3306
            },
          - {
              - cidr_blocks      = []
              - description      = ""
              - from_port        = 5432
              - ipv6_cidr_blocks = []
              - prefix_list_ids  = []
              - protocol         = "tcp"
              - security_groups  = [
                  - "sg-00000000",
                ]
              - self             = false
              - to_port          = 5432
            },
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can't mix** `egress` defined in `aws_security_group` with `aws_security_group_rule` resources. From [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group):

> Terraform currently provides both a standalone Security Group Rule resource (a single ingress or egress rule), and a Security Group resource with ingress and egress rules defined in-line. At this time you **cannot use a Security Group with in-line rules in conjunction with any Security Group Rule resources**. Doing so will cause a conflict of rule settings and will overwrite rules.

You can only use one of those, not both.

Comment: Yea, indeed this is the right answer, I just go confused because I had a similar setup without `for_each` and it was working normally.
Thanks

Comment: @Matteo No problem. Glad it worked out :-)